# Azure Search filter on collections

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Our index looks like  (this is from the query explorer) :

```
  "value": [
        {
            "@search.score": 1.5390168,
            "key": "xxx",
            "content": null,
            "fileSize": null,
            "filenames": [
                "File 1.docx",
                "File 1.docx",
                "File 1.docx",
            ],
            "paths": [
                "\\\\Server\\Share\FolderA",
                "\\\\Server\\Share\FolderB",
                "\\\\Server\\Share\FolderC",
            ]
        },
```

This showing that `File 1.doc` exists in more than once place, but we store it once in azure blob storange and thats why we have one key, the `xxx` is the blob storage key.

I have been reading the docs [OData Expression Syntax for Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/odata-expression-syntax-for-azure-search) but I don't see an example that allows us to filter with a startswith or contains from the collection.

I have tried

```
var searchParameters = new SearchParameters()
{
    Filter = @"paths/any(t: t gt '\\Server\Share')", 
};
```

We need to be able to search for the contents of a file for a given path.

*EDIT*

Our `CosmosDb` database has the view of the data as it's represented to the user, this database has `links` to the blob, so the other option would be to index the `CosmosDb` and have the indexer follow the links to the blobs, the documentation does not suggest that this is possible. Or, would we be better to write our own `indexer` and host this as an `azure function`.

We have one row per document and a pointer to the blob, many document rows can point to the same blob.

Comment: Well, *if* it works, the OData syntax would be `paths/any(t: startswith(t, '\\Server\Share'))`.

Comment: Hmm, seems like you can't use arbitrary functions in lambdas with Search. You can check the docs for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/OData-Expression-Syntax-for-Azure-Search

Comment: aye, I tried that :) I am reading the docs right now :) ... again :) I don't think its supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this with

```
var searchParameters = new SearchParameters()
{
    Filter = @"search.ismatch('""\\\\server\\share\\path""','paths','simple','all')",
};
```

I will do some more testing and update this answer if needed

Comment: Using search.ismatch is the right thing to do if you want to filter using a partial term. Regular filter expressions need to match the query terms exactly. You can learn more how to customize how the indexed or query terms are processed from this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture.